# Loading fxml file in main

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

i did this tutorial from youtube, and i have the same code than the tutorial but i did my proper fxml with Scenebuilder.
Here is the code: https://github.com/AlmasB/FXTutorials/tree/master/src/com/almasb/calc
I have the same Main, same Controller and same Model..
When i try to compile it says to me :

```
`Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1394438858.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:12)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1252716230.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/21202996.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/2040495657.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1558600329.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main

package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
```

This is my main :

```
    package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/Calculatorview.fxml"));
  //    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/Calculatorview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } 
       catch(Exception e)    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my fxml file :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.embed.swing.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="700.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.19063545150501673" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="32.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextField alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="638.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="47.0" />
                           </font>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="515.0" prefWidth="498.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane layoutX="90.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="319.0" prefWidth="638.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="116.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="95.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="116.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="95.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <effect>
                              <Blend />
                           </effect>
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperator" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EE543A; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="=" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="620.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperator" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EE543A; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="620.0" layoutY="299.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperator" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EE543A; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="620.0" layoutY="203.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperator" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EE543A; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="×" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="620.0" layoutY="107.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperator" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EE543A; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="÷" GridPane.columnIndex="7">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="532.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="76.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="C" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="358.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="362.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="69.0" prefWidth="88.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="M-" GridPane.columnIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="28.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="e" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="1/x" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="28.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="√" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="MC" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="28.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="M+" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="27.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="x²" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="tan" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="28.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="sin" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="xʸ" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="log" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="28.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button graphicTextGap="0.0" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="cos" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="26.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text=")">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="x³" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="98.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="(" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="95.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="96.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="98.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="96.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="±" GridPane.columnIndex="5">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="29.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="76.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="35.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="7" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="619.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="81.0" style="-fx-background-color: #EE543A; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="\%" GridPane.columnIndex="6">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="29.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="π" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="462.0" layoutY="202.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumpad" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="95.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9E9D9B; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="." GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button graphicTextGap="0.0" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="cosh" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="22.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="172.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="sinh" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="25.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="172.0" layoutY="138.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="tanh" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System" size="24.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="91.0" layoutY="266.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="10ʸ" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="30.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="253.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #60646D; -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;" text="MR" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="28.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

New Main :
[image: file structure]

Comment: Can you double check to see if root is not null? It is a NullPointerException at the start method and the root could be the one. Look at the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html , maybe the example might help

Comment: it says it's null because he can't load the fxml file evene if i put the corret PATH into "getResource".
Just added the FXML file

Comment: Seems like an issue with loading the .fxml see here it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754214/how-to-use-fxmlloader-load-javafx-2

Comment: Are you sure that the .fxml file is in the path specified and has the same name? Not likely that it's an issue because you would get a different exception however it's good to check.

Comment: Yes my fxml file is in the same folder than the main.java, i mean : src/application/.
However i tried to put "Calculatorview.fxml" without application but it doesn't worked too

Comment: Can you try replacing getClass().getResource(...) with getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Calculatorview.fxml"). Keep the .fxml in the same package as main. Just to be sure, it is Calculatorview.fxml not CaculatorView.fxml.

Comment: So i just did what you asked :
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Calculatorview.fxml"));
but it didn't worked, i tried with ("/application/Calculatorview.fxml") etc..

And yes it's Calculatorview.fxml and not CalculatorView.fxml .

Comment: Maybe it's launch(args) ?

Comment: Are you using any IDE (i.e. Eclipse, NetBeans) and any build too (i.e. Maven, Ant)? Or none. The path to .fxml will be different if you are using a build tool

Comment: I'm using Eclipse And i launch the program with ctrl+F11. I added javafx with e(fx)clipse. That's all

Comment: It all depends on how your IDE is configured, what is your project structure. It is difficult to give you an exact answer. You need try accessing the .fxml with ("/Caculatorview.fxml") and if that didn't work then move it to resource directory and reference it ("Calculatorview.fxml") only and see what happens. The main problem is the classpath. See the many posts about javafx in here like previous one I commented or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266492/location-is-required-exception-when-loading-fxml-file and find the right location for .fxml file. Good luck.

Comment: I just tried every solutions in the posts you linked but i got the same errors again.. Maybe i'm missing something in the configurations of the project?

Comment: Find the file `Main.class`. Is the FXML file in the same folder?

Comment: The file Main.class is in bin/application.
The FXML file is in the folder bin/application/view

Comment: Nowhere in your question have you mentioned a `viee` folder before. You need `getClass().getResource("view/Calculatorview.fxml")`

Comment: As i said in the comment of your answer, i said i changed the structure to try a new solution but at first time it Calculatorview.fxml was in the same folder than Main.class and i also added getClass().getResource("view/Calculatorview.fxml")

Comment: I fixed the problem ! :D

Comment: And I was so disappointed at myself for not being able to answer you correctly that today morning, I setup my system and reproduced the error and fixed it. See my answer, most probably you did something similiar. Programming is all about never giving up :P

Comment: Thank you alot Raf and James !
It was veru useful for me and it's true, Programing is all about never giving up ! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. I tried to setup my environment with Java 1.8 and tried the tutorial from the provided link. Here is what I did.

1. Installed Elcipse Kepler (Java EE)
2. Followed instructions here for e(fx)clipse https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html
3. Installed all the libs/jars as shown below

[image]

After above, I create a new Java project in the eclipse. I right clicked on the project and created two **Source Folders** namely

```
src/main/java 
src/main/resources
```

Then I right clicked on the src/main/java and created new package and named it **application**. Under application I created 4 java classes and copied across the content from the tutorial link. I did modify the package on top of each java file to reflect the **application** only.

Here are the java classes

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ui.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Text output;

    private long number1 = 0;
    private String operator = "";
    private boolean start = true;

    private Model model = new Model();

    @FXML
    private void processNumpad(ActionEvent event) {
        if (start) {
            output.setText("");
            start = false;
        }

        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
        output.setText(output.getText() + value);
    }

    @FXML
    private void processOperator(ActionEvent event) {
        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();

        if (!"=".equals(value)) {
            if (!operator.isEmpty())
                return;

            operator = value;
            number1 = Long.parseLong(output.getText());
            output.setText("");
        }
        else {
            if (operator.isEmpty())
                return;

            output.setText(String.valueOf(model.calculate(number1, Long.parseLong(output.getText()), operator)));
            operator = "";
            start = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
package application;

public class Model {

    public long calculate(long number1, long number2, String operator) {
        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                return number1 + number2;
            case "-":
                return number1 - number2;
            case "*":
                return number1 * number2;
            case "/":
                if (number2 == 0)
                    return 0;

                return number1 / number2;
        }

        System.out.println("Unknown operator - " + operator);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and ui.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.beans.property.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>

<VBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="300" prefHeight="300" fx:controller="application.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <fx:define>
        <Font fx:id="FONT" size="18" />
    </fx:define>

    <StackPane alignment="CENTER">
        <Rectangle fill="TRANSPARENT" stroke="GRAY" width="230" height="50" />
        <Text fx:id="output" font="$FONT" />
    </StackPane>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="7" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="8" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="9" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="/" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="4" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="5" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="6" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="*" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="1" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="2" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="3" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="-" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="0" prefWidth="110" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="=" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
        <Button text="+" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

</VBox>
```

I had issues with Java source library (reference to JRE) and the jfxrt.jar files. So I did the following

1. Removed the referenced library
2. Removed the external jar that was referenced
3. Right clicked on the project and choose **Properties**
4. Choose **Java Build Path**
5. Clicked on **Add Library** on the right side of the window and added **JRE System Library** as shown below
6. Added external jar **jfxrt.jar**

[image]

After adding the above, the code was resolved and there were no issues.

Remember, I placed **ui.fxml** under **src/main/resources** folder. So when I run the project as **Java Application** initially, it complained and give me the same exception as you are facing. So I changed the "ui.fxml" to "/ui.fxml" and boom, I saw the calculator.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ui.fxml"));
```

See below the screenshot, I hope these steps help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
NullPointerException: Location is required
```

from the line where you are calling `FXMLLoader.load(...)` indicates that the URL you provided for the FXML file is `null`: i.e. the path to the resource is incorrect.

`getClass().getResource()` will search for a resource on the classpath relative to the current class. According to the screen shot you linked, `Main` is in the package `appication` and `Calculatorview.fxml` is in `application.view`. So you need

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/Calculatorview.fxml"));
```

Alternatively, you can specify the fxml file relative to the classpath (instead of relative to the current class):

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/view/Calculatorview.fxml"));
```

(note the additional leading `/` compared to your code).

Note, of course, that this path is being searched at runtime, so you need to make sure the fxml file is deployed along with the *class* files when the code is compiled. In other words, if `Main` and `Calculatorview.fxml` are in the package `application`, somewhere you should have a folder called `application` containing `Main.class` (note, class file) and `Calculatorview.fxml`. This would typically be in a folder called `bin` or `classes`, depending on your IDE and its setup (or you will have the `application` structure in a jar file, if you're building a jar).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i already tried with this solution.
Maybe i'm missing something in the configurations of the project?

Comment: Show the folder structure for your *compiled* code (i.e, class files and other content of the directories that contain them).