# JavaFX not launching

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to launch up a project in JavaFX and am pretty lost at what I'm doing wrong.

The Main

```
package Software1C482;

/*
 * This program is explicitly for the use of Western Governers University's 
 * Software 1 submission by Andrew Whited.
 */


import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import ViewController.HomeWindowController;

/**
 *
 * @author Andrew Whited
 */
public class InventorySystem extends Application {
    private AnchorPane MainScreenView;
    private FXMLLoader viewLoader;

    public void initMainScreen(Stage window) throws IOException{

        viewLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        viewLoader.setLocation(InventorySystem.class.getResource("/ViewController/HomeWindow.fxml"));
        MainScreenView = viewLoader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(MainScreenView);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    public void showMainScreen() throws IOException{
        HomeWindowController controller = viewLoader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Inventory Mangement System"); 
        initMainScreen(primaryStage);
        showMainScreen();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The correlated files are as following.

HomeWindowController:

```
package ViewController;

import Model.Inventory;
import static Model.Inventory.getPartInventory;
import static Model.Inventory.getProductInventory;
import static Model.Inventory.removePart;
import static Model.Inventory.removeProduct;
import static Model.Inventory.validatePartDelete;
import Model.Part;
import Model.Product;
import Software1C482.InventorySystem;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Andrew
 */

//It's the home window.
public class HomeWindowController implements Initializable {

//Declaring the FXML parts.
    @FXML
    private TableView<Product> TableProduct;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Integer> ProductID, ProductInventoryLevel;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> ProductName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Double> ProductPPU;
    @FXML
    private Button ButtonProductAdd;
    @FXML
    private Button ButtonProductModify;
    @FXML
    private Button ButtonProductDelete;
    @FXML
    private Button ButtonPartSearch;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Part> TablePart;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Integer> PartID, PartInventoryLevel;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, String> PartName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Double> PartPPU;
    @FXML
    private TextField SearchFieldPart;
    @FXML
    private TextField SearchFieldProduct;

    private static Part modifyPart;
    private static int modifyPartIndex;
    private static Product modifyProduct;
    private static int modifyProductIndex;

    public static int partToModifyIndex() {
        return modifyPartIndex;
    }

    public static int productToModifyIndex() {
        return modifyProductIndex;
    }

    public HomeWindowController() {
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeExitClick(ActionEvent event) {

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.initModality(Modality.NONE);
        alert.setTitle("Confirmation");
        alert.setHeaderText("Confirm Exit");
        alert.setContentText("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please resume completing form.");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeAddPartsClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent addParts = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AddParts.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(addParts);
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeAddProductsClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent addProducts = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AddProducts.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(addProducts);
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeModifyPartsClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        modifyPart = TablePart.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        modifyPartIndex = getPartInventory().indexOf(modifyPart);
        Parent modifyParts = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ModifyParts.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(modifyParts);
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeModifyProductsClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        modifyProduct = TableProduct.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        modifyProductIndex = getProductInventory().indexOf(modifyProduct);
        Parent modifyProducts = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ModifyProducts.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(modifyProducts);
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeSearchProductsBtn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String searchProd = SearchFieldProduct.getText();
        int prodIndex = -1;
        if (Inventory.lookupProduct(searchProd) == -1) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Search Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Product not found.");
            alert.setContentText("The text entered does not match any Product.");
            alert.showAndWait();
        } else {
            prodIndex = Inventory.lookupProduct(searchProd);
            Product tempProd = Inventory.getProductInventory().get(prodIndex);
            ObservableList<Product> tempProdList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            tempProdList.add(tempProd);
            TableProduct.setItems(tempProdList);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeDeleteProductsClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Product product = TableProduct.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.initModality(Modality.NONE);
        alert.setTitle("Confirm Delete");
        alert.setHeaderText("Confirm?");
        alert.setContentText("Are you sure you want to delete " + product.getProductName() + "?");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            removeProduct(product);
            updateProductTableView();
            System.out.println("Product " + product.getProductName() + " was removed.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Product " + product.getProductName() + " was not removed.");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void PartSearchOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String searchPart = SearchFieldPart.getText();
        int partIndex = -1;
        if (Inventory.lookupPart(searchPart) == -1) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Search Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Part not found.");
            alert.setContentText("The text entered does not match any Part.");
            alert.showAndWait();
        } else {
            partIndex = Inventory.lookupPart(searchPart);
            Part tempPart = Inventory.getPartInventory().get(partIndex);
            ObservableList<Part> tempProdList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            tempProdList.add(tempPart);
            TablePart.setItems(tempProdList);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void HomeDeletePartsClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Part part = TablePart.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (validatePartDelete(part)) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Part Delete Error.");
            alert.setHeaderText("Part cannot be removed.");
            alert.setContentText("This part is used in a product.");
            alert.showAndWait();
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.initModality(Modality.NONE);
            alert.setTitle("Product Delete");
            alert.setHeaderText("Confirm?");
            alert.setContentText("Are you sure you want to delete " + part.getPartName() + "?");
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

            if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                removePart(part);
                updatePartTableView();
                System.out.println("Part " + part.getPartName() + " was removed.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Part " + part.getPartName() + " was not removed.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        PartID.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().partIDProperty().asObject());
        PartName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().partNameProperty());
        PartInventoryLevel.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().partInvProperty().asObject());
        PartPPU.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().partPriceProperty().asObject());
        ProductID.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productIDProperty().asObject());
        ProductName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productNameProperty());
        ProductInventoryLevel.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productInvProperty().asObject());
        ProductPPU.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productPriceProperty().asObject());
        updatePartTableView();
        updateProductTableView();
    }

    public void updatePartTableView() {
        TablePart.setItems(getPartInventory());
    }

    public void updateProductTableView() {
        TableProduct.setItems(getProductInventory());
    }

    public void setMainApp(InventorySystem mainApp) {
        updatePartTableView();
        updateProductTableView();
    }
}
```

And lastly
HomeWindow.FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.stage.Stage?>

<Stage xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ViewController.HomeWindowController">
    <scene>
        <Scene>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="941.0">
            <children>
               <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="53.0" text="Inventory Management System">
                  <font>
                     <Font size="18.0" />
                  </font>
               </Label>
               <Label layoutX="497.0" layoutY="108.0" text="Products">
                  <font>
                     <Font size="18.0" />
                  </font>
               </Label>
               <Rectangle arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="50.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="238.0" layoutX="479.0" layoutY="101.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeLineJoin="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" width="418.0" />
               <TextField fx:id="SearchFieldProduct" layoutX="737.0" layoutY="121.0" onAction="#HomeSearchProductsBtn" />
               <Button layoutX="682.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeSearchProductsBtn" text="Search" />
               <TableView fx:id="TableProduct" layoutX="501.0" layoutY="157.0" prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="374.0">
                  <columns>
                     <TableColumn fx:id="ProductID" prefWidth="77.0" text="Product ID" />
                     <TableColumn fx:id="ProductName" prefWidth="89.0" text="Product Name" />
                     <TableColumn fx:id="ProductInventoryLevel" prefWidth="94.0" text="Inventory Level" />
                     <TableColumn fx:id="ProductPPU" prefWidth="113.0" text="Price/Cost Per Unit" />
                  </columns>
               </TableView>
               <Button layoutX="624.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeAddProductsClick" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Add" />
               <Button layoutX="708.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeModifyProductsClick" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Modify" />
               <Button layoutX="789.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeDeleteProductsClick" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Delete" />
               <Label layoutX="67.0" layoutY="108.0" text="Parts">
                  <font>
                     <Font size="18.0" />
                  </font>
               </Label>
               <Rectangle arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="50.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="238.0" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="101.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeLineJoin="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" width="418.0" />
               <TextField fx:id="SearchFieldPart" layoutX="303.0" layoutY="121.0" />
               <Button layoutX="248.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#PartSearchOnAction" text="Search" />
               <TableView fx:id="TablePart" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="157.0" prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="374.0">
                  <columns>
                     <TableColumn fx:id="PartID" prefWidth="79.0" text="Part ID" />
                     <TableColumn fx:id="PartName" prefWidth="86.0" text="Part Name" />
                     <TableColumn fx:id="PartInventoryLevel" prefWidth="94.0" text="Inventory Level" />
                     <TableColumn fx:id="PartPPU" prefWidth="114.0" text="Price/Cost Per Unit" />
                  </columns>
               </TableView>
               <Button layoutX="190.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeAddPartsClick" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Add" />
               <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeModifyPartsClick" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Modify" />
               <Button layoutX="355.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeDeletePartsClick" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Delete" />
               <Button layoutX="749.0" layoutY="381.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HomeExitClick" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Exit" />
            </children></AnchorPane>
        </Scene>
    </scene>
</Stage>
```

I can reproduce the errors with only these three files. The errors are as follows.

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Reprex -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Reprex\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Reprex\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
run:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.stage.Stage cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane (javafx.stage.Stage and javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane are in module javafx.graphics of loader 'app')
    at InventorySystem/Software1C482.InventorySystem.initMainScreen(InventorySystem.java:32)
    at InventorySystem/Software1C482.InventorySystem.start(InventorySystem.java:48)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application Software1C482.InventorySystem
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Reprex\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1330: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Reprex\nbproject\build-impl.xml:902: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

As said before, this question has been rewritten to better address the new problem. I'm still very new, so this may be pretty poor for a reprex.

Comment: It appears to be a parsing error in your FXML file - the error references quite a bit of reflection, so there is likely an issue converting the FXML to usable Java classes.  Could you include the XML code in `HomeWindow.fxml`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct to make FXML members in Java 9 or 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082947/whats-the-correct-to-make-fxml-members-in-java-9-or-10)

Comment: @Slaw It didn't, but I may had done it wrong. I just added opens ViewController; to the module-info file. Viewcontroller being the package containing the FXMLs and controllers.

Comment: For example: If you have `com.example.Controller` then the module-info file should have a `opens com.example to javafx.fxml;` directive (or unqualified: `opens com.example;`). If you have done that and you're still getting an error, are you sure it's the same error? Note your current error is "_Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private javafx.scene.control.TableView ViewController.HomeWindowController.TableProduct accessible: module InventorySystem does not "opens ViewController" to module javafx.fxml_".

Comment: May also help: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627).

Comment: You're right. Half of the threads of errors are gone, that's one step done at least. Is it better practice  to update the question or post a new one with the new errors?

Comment: Ideally this question should be closed as a duplicate since the main issue presented in the question is answered by [What's the correct to make FXML members in Java 9 or 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082947). Your new issue would be best asked about in a new question. That being said, your original problem has been solved and an answer has already been posted trying to solve your new problem, so in this case I might suggest you [edit] your question to remove everything related to the old problem and retype it to cover the new problem, including a [mre] and _full_ error.

Comment: Note that the problem pointed out by [smac89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60495132/6395627) should be giving you a `ClassCastException`. The stack trace you provided does not show this. An `InvocationTargetException` is thrown when some method or constructor is invoked _via reflection_ somewhere in the call stack and said method or constructor throws an exception. The ITE wraps the "real" exception. Because of this, ITEs are largely a distraction and you must look at the `Caused by`s in the stack trace (see the _What is a stack trace..._ Q&A I linked to in a previous comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was that I didn't include the package in HomeWindow's FXML when linking to it's controller.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, your fxml contains `Stage` as the root element, but you are loading the object from the FXML as an `AnchorPane`.

The presence of the `InvocationTargetException` means that some constructor or field or method was called on `AnchorPane`, but that field/method does not exist on the object.

This is obvious because `Stage` is not a descendant of `AnchorPane`, so not even polymorphism can help you there; and when the FXMLLoader attempts to do something like `setScene` on the `AnchorPane`, this will fail.

---

You have two options for doing this:

1. Load the entire stage from FXML
2. Remove the stage declaration from FXML and just leave the root as a node.

I prefer the second option and this is also the more popular option. The first option is a bit redundant because javafx already provides you with a `Stage` in the `start` method, so I don't see the benefit in creating a new stage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.stage.Stage?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="941.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ViewController.HomeWindowController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="53.0" text="Inventory Management System">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="497.0" layoutY="108.0" text="Products">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="50.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="238.0" layoutX="479.0" layoutY="101.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeLineJoin="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" width="418.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="SearchFieldProduct" layoutX="737.0" layoutY="121.0" />
      <Button layoutX="682.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" />
      <TableView fx:id="TableProduct" layoutX="501.0" layoutY="157.0" prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="374.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="ProductID" prefWidth="77.0" text="Product ID" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="ProductName" prefWidth="89.0" text="Product Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="ProductInventoryLevel" prefWidth="94.0" text="Inventory Level" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="ProductPPU" prefWidth="113.0" text="Price/Cost Per Unit" />
         </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button layoutX="624.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Add" />
      <Button layoutX="708.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Modify" />
      <Button layoutX="789.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Delete" />
      <Label layoutX="67.0" layoutY="108.0" text="Parts">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="50.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="238.0" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="101.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeLineJoin="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" width="418.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="SearchFieldPart" layoutX="303.0" layoutY="121.0" />
      <Button layoutX="248.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#PartSearchOnAction" text="Search" />
      <TableView fx:id="TablePart" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="157.0" prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="374.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="PartID" prefWidth="79.0" text="Part ID" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="PartName" prefWidth="86.0" text="Part Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="PartInventoryLevel" prefWidth="94.0" text="Inventory Level" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="PartPPU" prefWidth="114.0" text="Price/Cost Per Unit" />
         </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button layoutX="190.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Add" />
      <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Modify" />
      <Button layoutX="355.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Delete" />
      <Button layoutX="749.0" layoutY="381.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Exit" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I would also change your code to this:

```
public class InventorySystem extends Application {
    private AnchorPane MainScreenView;
    private FXMLLoader viewLoader;

    public void initMainScreen(Stage window) throws IOException{

        viewLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        viewLoader.setLocation(InventorySystem.class.getResource("/ViewController/HomeWindow.fxml"));
        MainScreenView = viewLoader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(MainScreenView);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    public void showMainScreen() throws IOException{
        HomeWindowController controller = viewLoader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Inventory Mangement System"); 
        initMainScreen(primaryStage);
        showMainScreen();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try looking into this! Still not fully conscious of terminology so I may take a bit.

Comment: @Mataske just replace your current FXML with the one above and try again

Comment: It gave me an error on MainScreenView = loader.load(); line saying load wasn't a variable, so I changed that to viewLoader and it came up with what looks to be the same error log.

Comment: @Mataske see https://github.com/MVCE-Superstars/Javafx11-Launch

Comment: I think I did what was said right. The only part I didn't fully get was where to put the package options. I put them in Exclude from Jar file and I tried without. Regardless, compiling or running it is now saying 
error: file not found: InventorySystem.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>

Comment: After some testing I found it was where I was putting the additional compiler options causing the new error. On the bright side, swapping the FXML did fix a majority of the errors. Leaving just 
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InventorySystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1330: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InventorySystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:902: Java returned: 1